# Can't get openGL to link in ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, opengl

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I've seen a few posts related to openGL on Ubuntu, but none seem to relate to the problem I'm having.

For some reason whenever I try to build my project in eclipse-CDT I get the following console output:

```
    **** Build of configuration Debug for project windows ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/windows.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/windows.d" -MT"src/windows.d" -o "src/windows.o" "../src/windows.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/windows.cpp

Building target: windows
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "windows"  ./src/OGdisplay.o ./src/windows.o   -lGLEW -lGL -lSDL2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:45: recipe for target 'windows' failed
make: *** [windows] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

I've installed the mesa-common-Dev package and all the others I could find that have to do with opengl development, but it won't budge. I put: GLEW, GL, and SDL2 in libraries under the GCC C++ linker settings. It doesn't seem to have any issues finding SDL2 and GLEW, but for some reason just can't find GL.

I went to usr/include and can clearly see the GL folder with it's contents as well as SDL2(which it has no issues finding). I've tried the same thing in codeblocks with extremely simple code and get the same result saying it can't find GL.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04LTS with an nvidia GeForce GTX 1060. I'm also using the NVIDIA Xserver driver version 367.44. Under the nvidia Xserver settings in the OpenGL information sections it says it has version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 367.44 if that helps. If you need anymore information just let me know, I'm almost certain that it's something simple I'm not thinking of.

Here are my CDT linker settings if it'll let me post a pick:

[linker settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxHoo.png)

SOLUTION: I'm not sure it's much of a solution, but I reinstalled NVIDIA X server and it seems to be working fine now. Not sure what was orginally causing it though.

Comment: The problem isn't the header files in `/usr/include`, but the *library* file in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: You must specify both PATHS, /usr/include for '.h' files and /usr/lib for '.so' files.